# Git - remove unstaged changes to a file that has staged changes

Tags: git

I have a file that has some staged changes I added through `git add -p`

I would like to discard, or stash, the rest of the changes to that file, without touching the changes that I already added, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple checkout of the file should do what you want

```
git checkout -- $file
```